# JMF + mp3plugin.jar mp3 files is not playing

Tags: java, mp3, javasound, jmf

I have this code :

```
    package test;

import java.io.File;

import javax.media.Format;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.media.PlugInManager;
import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;

public class AudioTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Format input1 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEGLAYER3);
        Format input2 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEG);
        Format output = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR);
        PlugInManager.addPlugIn(
            "com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder",
            new Format[]{input1, input2},
            new Format[]{output},
            PlugInManager.CODEC
        );
        try{
            Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new MediaLocator(new File("1.mp3").toURI().toURL()));
            player.realize();
                        player.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

i'm trying to play an mp3 file, mp3plugin is added to the project lib as well as the jmf jar.
there's no error on the console but cant hear a sound.

the file is not playing. 
.wav files are playing fine.

any idea ?

Comment: Since 1.3 the J2SE has had Java Sound.  All that is needed to play a (short) MP3 is code seen on the [tag:javasound] info. page, and the `mp3plugin.jar` on the run-time class-path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JMF is a bad option. The project was abandoned long time ago.
I have answered a similar question here:

[Java - Error when trying to use mp3plugin for playing an mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959566/java-error-when-trying-to-use-mp3plugin-for-playing-an-mp3-file/14959818#14959818)

it might be usefull for you - Im using Java Sound

Comment: In your example, you left out the AudioPlayerListener.class. I'd like to implement this but I don't know the structure.

Answer (score 0):

The following is all I need to play music.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws NoPlayerException, CannotRealizeException, IOException {
    MediaLocator ml = new MediaLocator((new File("roar_of_future.mp3").toURL()));
    Player player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(ml);
    player.start();
}
```

So please make sure [mp3plugin.jar](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-137625.html) is in the classpath and your javasdk is  Java 8 (32bit) or 7 (32bit) because JMF is not working on Java 9 and above.